# How to reduce vertical distance between compounds in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

When writing reaction mechanism in chemfig with subscheme there are wide vertical gaps between the two compounds as seen in the figure attached.
[image]

How can I achieve the desired position shown in the fig.
Attempt so far

```
documentclass{book}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\setbondoffset{0pt}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\subscheme[-90]{
\chemfig{CH_3CH=[@{d}]CH_2}
\arrow{0[][][-10pt]}
\chemfig{@{e}Br-[@{f}]@{g}Br}
}
\ce{->}
\chemfig{CH_3\chemabove{C}{\scrp}HCH_2Br} \+ \chemfig{Br^{-}} 
\schemestop
\chemmove[cyan,>=latex,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]{ 
\draw[shorten >=1pt,->] (d) ..controls +(-90:1cm) and +(135:1cm) .. (e) ;} 
\chemmove[red,>=latex,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=2pt]{ 
\draw[shorten >=0pt,->] (f) ..controls +(-90:.5cm) and +(-90:1cm) .. (g) 
;}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjusting the dimensions of the invisible arrow between the propylene and the bromine should get you closer to the ecpected output.

I also replaced the deprecated

```
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\setbondoffset{0pt}
```

commands with

```
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em,
            bond offset=0pt}
```

to make the code compilable with `chemfig` versions newer than 1.3 (from march 2018).

Lastly, I included an alternative layout for the reaction, as reagents are usually drawn next to the reactant(s)  or above the reaction arrow, instead of somewhere below the reactant.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em,
            bond offset=0pt}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\subscheme[-90]{
\chemfig{CH_3CH=[@{d}]CH_2}
\arrow{0}[-90,0.25]
\chemfig{@{e}Br-[@{f}]@{g}Br}
}
\ce{->}
\chemfig{CH_3\chemabove{C}{\scrp}HCH_2Br} \+ \chemfig{Br^{-}} 
\schemestop
\chemmove[cyan,>=latex,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]{ 
\draw[shorten >=1pt,->] (d) ..controls +(-90:.75cm) and +(135:1cm) .. (e) ;} 
\chemmove[red,>=latex,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=2pt]{ 
\draw[shorten >=0pt,->] (f) ..controls +(-90:.5cm) and +(-90:1cm) .. (g) 
;}

\vspace{3cm}


\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3CH=[@{d}]CH_2}
\arrow{->[\chemfig{@{e}Br-[@{f}]@{g}Br}]}
\chemfig{CH_3\chemabove{C}{\scrp}HCH_2Br} \+ \chemfig{Br^{-}} 
\schemestop
\chemmove[cyan,>=latex,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]{ 
\draw[shorten >=1pt,->] (d) ..controls +(90:.75cm) and +(135:.75cm) .. (e) ;} 
\chemmove[red,>=latex,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=2pt]{ 
\draw[shorten >=0pt,->] (f) ..controls +(90:.5cm) and +(90:.5cm) .. (g) 
;}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two methods, using only commands from the "chemfig" package

1. Positioning Br2 after the end of the chemical reaction:

   ```
   \setchemfig{atom sep=1.5em,bond offset=0pt}

   \begin{document}

   \schemestart

   \chemfig{CH_3CH=[@{a},1.5]CH_2}

   \arrow{->} 

   \chemfig{CH_3\chemabove{C}{\scriptstyle+}HCH_2Br} 

   \+ \chemfig{Br^{-}}

   \arrow(@{a}--){0}[320,.6]\chemfig{@{b}Br-[@{c},1.5]@{d}Br}

   %---------------------------------------------------------------

   \chemmove{

       \draw[red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=1pt](a).. controls +(270:8mm) and +(90:8mm)..(b);

       \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](c).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(d);

    }

   \schemestop

   \end{document}
   ```
2. or placing Br2 at the beginning, but you will need to reposition the reaction arrow

   ```
    \begin{document}

    \schemestart

    \chemfig{CH_3CH=[@{a},1.5]C@{z}H_2}

    \arrow(@{a}--){0}[320,.6]\chemfig{@{b}Br-[@{c},1.5]@{d}Br}

    \arrow(@{z}--){->} 

    \chemfig{CH_3\chemabove{C}{\scriptstyle+}HCH_2Br}

    \+ \chemfig{Br^{-}}

    %---------------------------------------------------------------

    \chemmove{

    \draw[red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=1pt](a).. controls +(270:8mm) and +(90:8mm)..(b); 

    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](c).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(d);

    }

    \schemestop

    \end{document}
   ```

Both have a very similar result.

[image]

With bromine at angle 270

```
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    %
    \chemfig{CH_3CH=[@{a},1.5]C@{z}H_2}
    %
    \arrow(@{a}--){0}[320,.6]\chemfig{@{b}Br-[@{c},1.5]@{d}Br}
    %
    \arrow(@{z}--){->}
    %
    \chemfig{CH_3@{y}\chemabove{C}{\scriptstyle+}HCH_2Br}
    %
    \arrow(@{y}--){0}[-90,.3]\+ \chemfig{Br^{-}}
    %
    %---------------------------------------------------------------
    \chemmove{
        \draw[red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=1pt](a).. controls +(270:8mm) and +(90:8mm)..(b);
        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](c).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(d);  
    }
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to place the last bromine atom at 90° or 270° and the product was not aligned with the arrow. Your kind treatment will be appreciated

Comment: @Kidegalize -- I added more code to my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: apologies for I was not clear. The first step is very fine. I have drawn an arrow from Br^- to the C with + above it. I would like this Br to be at 270° in the final product.

Comment: @Kidegalize -- This?  \chemfig{CH_3CHCH_2Br(-[6,,3]Br)}